# python convert multiline string sql query to singleline

Tags: python

I have a sql where that I have formatted with new lines and multiple tabs and spaces. I have this for example, but indented multiple times:

```
q = f'''
    UPDATE
        `table`
    SET
        `col1` = 1
    WHERE
        `another col` = 2
    AND 
        `final col` = 3
    '''
```

How can I convert the query into a single line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
width = 100
textwrap.shorten(q, width)
```

giving

```
'UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = 1 WHERE `another col` = 2 AND `final col` = 3'
```

but you need to be careful if the SQL values contain multiple spaces, for example

```
SET `col1` = "a  b  c"
```

as they will be collapsed too.

Answer (score 0):

For IDLE editor, use Alt+Q to bring selected code in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

SQL databases are not too fussy about SQL formatting. They will take multi-line or single line queries just fine. For readability (for humans), a multi-line string is often preferred.

Here's your one liner:

```
q = "UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = 1 WHERE `another col` = 2 AND `final col` = 3"
```

I kept your backticks ``, but I don't really know what they're for. Maybe some DBs use backtick for tables or columns that have spaces in their names?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the `shlex.shlex` class to

1. Preserve quote (the back tick) **`**
2. Preserve number of spaces inside the the quotes

```py
import shlex

q = f'''
    UPDATE
        `table`
    SET
        `col1` = 1
    WHERE
        `another col` = 2
    AND 
        `final col` = 3
'''

tokens = shlex.shlex(q)
tokens.quotes += "`"  # The back tick is consider a quote char
new_q = " ".join(tokens)
print(new_q)
```

Output:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = 1 WHERE `another col` = 2 AND `final col` = 3
```

#### Notes

- The `shlex.shlex` class can split a text into tokens, which are separated by one or more spaces
- I also tell shlex to consider the back tick as a quote char, which preserves the spaces within
- Using this class is much better than using `str.split` because it understands quotes, whereas `str.split` does not.